# Laravel artisan optimize Best Practices

Tags: php, laravel, optimization, laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to fully understand the Laravel (5.1) `artisan optimize` command and best practices, but the documentation seems lacking. I don't have Composer installed on the production server so, specifically, I want to know what files are modified or created when running `artisan optimize --force` on development that must get pushed to production. The goal being not to blow up the app in production! After running the command, I see the following files have been modified:

```
\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php
\vendor\composer\ - the entire directory
\vendor\autoload.php
```

Am I overthinking this, or do I just push these files to production and I'm good to go? Also, what is the best practice regarding when to run `artisan optimize`? Each time a new model is created? What about controllers, routes and helper classes?

Lastly, I see the `\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php` file is a whopping 548KB and almost 17K lines! Is that really considered optimal?

Comment: You certainly can simply push compiled.php and the vendor folder to production in order to deploy. And this would in fact have a few advantages over using composer/artisan to do so, such as not relying on additional 3rd party servers to deploy your app. But I've never heard of anyone doing it that way, so I'd hesitate to call it a "best practice".

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[edit - As @crishoj says, as of Laravel 5.5, php artisan optimize is no longer needed]

Normal Laravel practice *is* to have composer installed on your production server.

These are the steps [Envoyer](https://envoyer.io) (made by Laravel's creator) takes to deploy an app on production -- I've annotated them below:

```
# Install application dependencies, such as the Laravel framework itself.
#
# If you run composer update in development and commit the `composer.lock`
# file to your repository, then `composer install` will install the exact
# same versions in production.
composer install --no-interaction

# Clear the old boostrap/cache/compiled.php
php artisan clear-compiled

# Recreate boostrap/cache/compiled.php
php artisan optimize

# Migrate any database changes
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: composer install --no-interaction --no-dev for optimization on production.

Comment: _that gives better performance than hundreds of small files._
do you have any evidence or benchmarks of this when using APC - it's not clear to me why it would help.

Comment: @Yehosef Just personal experience; it's a trivial test to run, though. Just time your site with and without `bootstrap\cache\compiled.php`. Be sure to update us with your new evidence! I'm a big fan of benchmarks -- see my Laravel benchmarks at https://github.com/claar/laravel-benchmarks/

Comment: @Ben - I don't use laravel currently - if you do could you try the benchmark?  As you said - it should be trivial to run and it would help validate your claims.   I'm asking because I tried a similar optimization on a different code base and I didn't see any benefit.

Comment: @Yehosef Well what do you know, you're correct. Running a simple `ab -n 500 http://app.vagrant` benchmark 4 times, twice with and without `compiled.php`, all 4 runs were within 1 second of each other. I've removed the claim from the answer. https://gist.github.com/claar/6ea72454477fc1afb7c8

Comment: @Yehosef For past versions of PHP and Laravel, I saw dramatic performance increases from using a heavily optimized compiled.php. I guess APC has improved; thanks for encouraging me to look into this.

Comment: @Ben - if you're running without APC it seems clear there should be a benefit.  And even if you're using APC, generally it's configured to stat the files for changes if it needs to recompile - it could be os/disk improvements make that cost less noticeable.  Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: I don't know how Laravel handers error catching or logging - but I use Kohana and they have a good lib for reporting the stack trace. A downside of the compile is that it will be in one file and it'll be harder to find the right place in the real file to fix/debug. I'm not sure what's the benefit of this feature -  if you care about performance enough to compile, you should be running APC and it doesn't matter.  And if you don't care about performance and are not running apc, you don't care about performance and it doesn't matter.

Comment: Now we can add also `php artisan config:cache` and `php artisan route:cache`, but they must be run on the server because config values are linked to absolute paths and thus won't work if you generate config cache on your dev machine and then copy to the production server.

Comment: Running `php artisan clear-compiled` is not necessary as `php artisan optimize` overwrites compiled.php.

Comment: Whoa whoa, _"Normal Laravel practice is to have composer installed on your production server."_

No. It's not.  You can have composer on your *build* server, but on a production machine, you're long past needing it.

Comment: It's been a few years and many updates to Laravel since this answer - would it be possible to update it with how Envoyer currently handles this? I couldn't find a GitHub repo anyway so I'm guessing it's not open source.

Answer (score 23):

As of [Laravel 5.5](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade), `php artisan optimize` is not longer required.

Comment: `php artisan optimize:clear` for clearing the cache is still working well

Comment: i end up using it ever so often to clear cache. command does what it supposed to do