# How to avoid optimize command for every small changes in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have made some changes on a Blade file using  text editor and then refreshed my page but unable to see new added content and noticed that  (it's loading the old content from Blade file).

code in route(web.php)

```
Route::get('about', function () {

             return view('about');
});
```

// code in view file(about.php)

```
<p>some text in about file</p>
```

I've tried the following:

```
php artisan optimize
```

then It worked fine i.e new added html lines visible but why for every small changes I need to optimize server

Comment: Maybe because `optimize` is caching content and your new changes is not visible, no matter if it's small or big change?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel artisan optimize Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31895854/laravel-artisan-optimize-best-practices)

Comment: @Justinas but why otimize everytime even for dot also use terminal,can u please tell me without optimize command automatically trigger like in other framework codeigniter simply hit url again

Comment: Try running `php artisan optimize:clear` once. After that the response shouldn't be cached anymore. When running `php artisan optimize` you simply refresh your cache rather than removing it completely.

Comment: @PtrTon you should write up your comment as the answer