# can not get env file attribute after using php artisan optimize in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-cache

I am getting attribute value from env file like this

```
{{env('PUSHER_APP_KEY')}}
```

It stops working when i use `php artisan optimize` command

Then Again I have to use `php artisan config:clear`

What could be the solution of it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel artisan optimize Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31895854/laravel-artisan-optimize-best-practices)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better create a `config` file in `config folder`

For example name `config` file as `constant.php`

```
<?php

return [
'pusher_app_key'=>env('PUSHER_APP_KEY')
];
```

then you can access like this

```
{{config('constant.pusher_app_key')}}
```

once you have created config:cache then it wont read from env file.

Comment: yes it works but what was the reason behind it?

Comment: once you cache data using php artisan config:cache then it wont read from env for performance

Comment: optimze is to increase app performance its like cache