# The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. + Laravel

Tags: laravel, post

I am trying to update .

**I am getting the error**

The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

Following are the code

**In Route**

`Route::post('editcountries','App\Http\Controllers\backend\admineditcountryController@editcountries');`

**In Controller**

```
 function editcountries(Request $request)
    {


    $country_en = $request->input('country_en');
    $country_ar = $request->input('country_ar');
    $id = $request->input('idd');
    $cstatus = 1;

    if (isset($request->status))
    $cstatus = 1;
    else
    $cstatus = 0;


    $isUpdateSuccess = country::where('id',$id)->update(['country_en'=> $country_en,
                                                                'country_ar'=> $country_ar,
                                                                'status' => $cstatus
                                                               ]);

    $this->clearToastr();
    session()->put('updated','Information updated Successfully.');
    return view('backend.adminaddcountry');

    }
```

**In blade**

```
 <form action="editcountries" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                   
                    @csrf
                    {{-- @method('PUT') --}}
                    {{-- <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">" --}}

                  <div class="input-style-1">
                    <label>Country Name in English </label>
                    <input type="text" name="country_en" placeholder="Country Name in English"
                    value='{{ $clist->country_en }}' required/>
                  </div>

                  <div class="input-style-1">
                    <label>Country Name in Arabic</label>
                    <input type="text" dir="rtl" name="country_ar" placeholder="اسم الدولة بالعربية" value='{{ $clist->country_ar }}' />
                  </div>
                  <!-- end input -->

                  <div class="form-check form-switch toggle-switch">
                    <input class="form-check-input" name="status" type="checkbox" id="toggleSwitch2" @if($clist->status==1)
                    checked=""
                    @else
                    @endif>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="toggleSwitch2">Enable or disable the country.</label>
                  </div>

                  <input type="hidden" id="idd" name="idd" value="{{ $clist->id }}" />
                  <br>



                  <button class="main-btn primary-btn btn-hover text-center">Update</button>

                  </form>
```

I tried using

```
@method('PUT')
```

but then getting error

`The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.`

Please help

I tried putting

I tried using

```
@method('PUT')
```

but then getting error

`The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.`

Please help

Comment: If you use `@method('PUT')` you need `Route::put` in the routes file.

Comment: what URL are you currently on when you try to submit this form? you are using a relative path for the form so it could be going to somewhere you don't expect ... what is the URL of the page you are seeing this error on?

Answer (score 0):

You might have your routes cached, you can try running the following commands in the terminal:

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan route:cache
```

You should get rid of the code you added making it a put request, unless that is what you want. If you want it to be a PUT route you need to use:

```
Route::put
```

Otherwise if you still can't figure it out, go through your routes file and check for any other routes that match "editcountries". Sometimes the order you put the routes can cause conflicts with other routes, like a resource route for example. However I would say if you get rid of the PUT code in the blade file, and run the route cache commands I provided, you should have it working with the post route.

Comment: no. it didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

## How to Debug:

1. Run: `php artisan route::list --path admineditcountryController`
2. If you do not see your controller in the output run `php artisan route:clear`

I would **not recommend** running `route:cache` as you'll have to continuously `route:clear` any time you change/add/remove routes — set that up in your CI to only run in PROD. In fact — you should just run `php artisan optimize` in production and it'll do a bunch of fancy performance Laravel magic for ya ([further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31895854/laravel-artisan-optimize-best-practices))

## Other Improvements (PR Comments)

### 1. Follow PSR-2 File/Class/Namespace NAming

Aside, make sure your folder & namespaces are following PSR-2 (CamelCase)

```php
App\Http\Controllers\backend\admineditcountryController
# should be
App\Http\Controllers\Backend\AdminEditCountryController
# even better (Namespaced) 
App\Http\Controllers\Backend\Admin\CountryController
```

### 2. Reference controllers using an import

This is a bit cleaner (PHP 7+) + try utilizing `Route::resource` + Laravel Action Verbs as controller function names [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller)

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\Backend\AdminEditCountryController;

/* Simplified - Best practice: use dashes as URL delimiters '-' */
Route::post('edit-countries', AdminEditCountryController::class . '@editcountries');

/* PRO VERSION */
Route::group('admin')->prefix('admin')->name('admin.')->group( function () {
  // AdminEditCountryController@update()
  Route::resource('country', Admin\CountryController::class)->only(['update']); 
});
```

### 3. Extra Credit

Try generating your controllers (benefits from PSR-2 compliant namespace & folder layouts):

```bash
php artisan make:controller Admin\CountryController --resource
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it.

**Route**

```
Route::post('/editcountries','App\Http\Controllers\backend\admineditcountryController@editcountries');
```

**Controller**

```
  function editcountries(Request $request)
    {


    $country_en = $request->input('country_en');
    $country_ar = $request->input('country_ar');
    $id = $request->input('idd');
    $cstatus = 1;

    if (isset($request->status))
    $cstatus = 1;
    else
    $cstatus = 0;


    $isUpdateSuccess = country::where('id',$id)->update(['country_en'=> $country_en,
                                                                'country_ar'=> $country_ar,
                                                                'status' => $cstatus
                                                               ]);

    $this->clearToastr();
    session()->put('updated','Information updated Successfully.');

    $data = country::where('id', '=',  $id)->first();
    return view('backend.admineditcountry',['clist'=>$data]);

    }
```

**Blade**

```
   <form action="/editcountries" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    @csrf

                  <div class="input-style-1">
                    <label>Country Name in English </label>
                    <input type="text" name="country_en" placeholder="Country Name in English"
                    value='{{ $clist->country_en }}' required/>
                  </div>

                  <div class="input-style-1">
                    <label>Country Name in Arabic</label>
                    <input type="text" dir="rtl" name="country_ar" placeholder="اسم الدولة بالعربية" value='{{ $clist->country_ar }}' />
                  </div>
                  <!-- end input -->

                  <div class="form-check form-switch toggle-switch">
                    <input class="form-check-input" name="status" type="checkbox" id="toggleSwitch2" @if($clist->status==1)
                    checked=""
                    @else
                    @endif>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="toggleSwitch2">Enable or disable the country.</label>
                  </div>

                  <input type="hidden" id="idd" name="idd" value="{{ $clist->id }}" />
                  <br>



                  <button class="main-btn primary-btn btn-hover text-center">Update</button>

                  </form>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).