# How solve "Illuminate\Console\Command" not found?

Tags: php, laravel, cron, scheduled-tasks, production-environment

I have a web application in a production environment. The path to the command is correctly set on the server, but it still throws error "Illuminate\Console\Command" not found. Solutions tryied ->  (composer dump-autoload, deleted vendor and reinstalled with composer install, php artisan optimize). Nothing works :/

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Illuminate\Console\Command" not found in app/Console/Commands/DeleteExpiredData.php:10
> Stack trace:
> #0 {main}
> thrown in /app/Console/Commands/DeleteExpiredData.php on line 10

Illuminatie is available in vendor and correctly installed, I did try composer dump-autoload but it still doesn't work.

This is my command

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class DeleteExpiredData extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'delete-expired-data';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Delete old data from database';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $now = Carbon::now();
        Log::info('Starting app:delete-expired-data command');

        DB::table('available_business_hour')
            ->whereDate('day', '<', $now->startOfDay())
            ->delete();

        Log::info('Expired command executed successfully');
    }

}
```

This is my kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule): void
    {
        $schedule->command('delete-expired-data')->daily();
        // $schedule->command('delete-unconfirmed-res')->everyFiveMinutes();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     */
    protected function commands(): void
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
```

And this is composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The skeleton application for the Laravel framework.",
    "keywords": ["laravel", "framework"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "erlandmuchasaj/laravel-gzip": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "jantinnerezo/livewire-alert": "^3.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.10",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.3",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.8",
        "livewire/livewire": "^3.4",
        "propaganistas/laravel-phone": "^5.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.23",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.18",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^7.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.1",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi",
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --force --tag=livewire:assets --ansi"

        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

I'll be glad if anybody has idea how can I solve that issue :) Thank you

So I crated this custom script in www folder

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';

$commandName = 'app:delete-expired-data';

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class);

$input = new Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput(['artisan', 'schedule:run']);

$status = $kernel->handle($input, new Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput);

$kernel->terminate($input, $status);

exit($status);
```

In server cron log I have got this, is there any possible solution how to solve that? Because I can't edit proc_open on server.. :(

```
Tue 05 Mar 2024 04:35:23 PM CET Executing /srv/www/myDomain//barbershop27/scheduler.php

  2024-03-05 16:35:23 Running ['artisan' delete-expired-data] ....... 8ms DONE
  â‡‚ '/usr/bin/php8.2' 'artisan' delete-expired-data > '/dev/null' 2>&1
```

But in storage/logs it shows this error

```
production.ERROR: The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\LogicException(code: 0): The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation. at /srv/www/myDomain/barbershop27/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:147)
[stacktrace]
#0 /srv/www/myDomain/barbershop27/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php(192): Symfony\Component\Process\Process->__construct(Array, '/srv/www/myDomain...', NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

Comment: Does `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php` exist?

Comment: IT does ye :)  @aynber

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31895854/laravel-artisan-optimize-best-practices

Comment: @dz0nika unfortunately iit didn't help..

Comment: Okay, this is really strange. Can you please update your question to include your `composer.json` file and your `app/Console/Kernel.php` file?

Comment: @EyadBereh I inserted it now :)

Comment: Nothing unusual here. Okay, I can see that you're calling this command as cronjob. How are you doing this? What command are you using?

Comment: @EyadBereh how do you think that? All what i can do on my server on shared hosting is setup path to script where is the logic for task, so i think i need to setup path to DeleteExpiredData.php, this file is in /barbershop27/app/Console/Commands so on the server I setuped path as  /barbershop27/app/Console/Commands/DeleteExpiredData.php and it should run command, but it doesnt happening, instead of this  I am getting error in server cron log which I described in my question above.

Comment: The issue we're facing here is that the `Illuminate\Console\Command` class isn't being loaded at all by the framework. 
Are you using the command `php artisan schedule:run` or the command `php /barbershop27/app/Console/Commands/DeleteExpiredData.php` ? Because I could produce the same error in your question only by using the second command.

Comment: @EyadBereh nothing from this, All what i can do is in webhosting administration add path to script like this -> /barbershop27/app/Console/Commands/DeleteExpiredData.php ,, If I add php before path it throws me "Enter valid file name in within space of domain." and if i run php artisan schedule:run  from SSH terminal it shows that here arent any scheduled tasks, but its nonsense, cause i have task registered correctly in Kernel.php :/

Comment: This is manual on hosting for how to set path like example --> Add File name - PHP Script. Enter relative path (case sensitive) from root directory of your domain. Enter the path from the same level where direcory www is. Eg. /www/cron/soubor.php

Comment: Okay, very nice. In this case, inside the PHP script path enter as follows: `/barbershop27/artisan schedule:run` it should work

Comment: @EyadBereh I did try  that...but it doesn't allow input colon..:(

Comment: Oh man, this is unbelievable. Why on earth would they do that?
Okay, there's still a solution: create a new command and call it for example `AlternativeScheduleRun`. Inside it, define the `$signature` attribute to be `schedule-run`, and inside the `handle()` method do the call `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::call("schedule:run");` 
Now in your control panel, use the command `/barbershop27/artisan schedule-run`

Comment: Thats still a problem.. still out of domain scope, I literally can use just directly path to file.. this is answer from hostin support -->  Hello, you set up cron to point to a .php file without any parameters. Cron will then execute the specified file at the configured intervals.

If I have this file located, for example, in the www/cron directory, then the cron setting will be: www/cron/myscript.php

If I have this file located, for example, in the cron directory at the same level as www, then the cron setting path will be: /cron/myscript.php

Comment: @EyadBereh I did updated question with new informations about problem :/

Comment: @jwchild Okay, this means that we've hit the wall and reached a dead-end. The hosting provider has disabled the `proc_open()`. This is usually done by hosting providers for "security reasons".
So now what? You have to contact the support and tell them to enable this function. This is usually done by adjusting the `disable_functions` directive inside the `php.ini` file.

Comment: ..this is their answer--> Hello,

all the mentioned functions are not allowed on the web hosting, as indicated by the PHP info:
https://php82.hukot.net/
and it's not possible to enable them.
Have a nice day.

Comment: @jwchild Well, unfortunately, this means that you need to look for a different hosting provider as there's nothing further to be done here.

Answer (score 0):

Okey,, finally a I did solve that with this option, and it works! :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';

$container = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Container\Container::class);

$kernel = $container->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class);

$commandName = 'delete-expired-data';

$input = new Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput(['console.php', $commandName]);

$status = $kernel->handle($input, new Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput);

$kernel->terminate($input, $status);

exit($status);
```

Comment: What is this file? And how do you run it ?

Comment: That's separate php script placed in to laravel root directory, whioh is running script separately

Comment: I don't think that's an optimal solution to the problem, but if it works then it works.

Comment: @EyadBereh it's last solution which can work here unfortunately.